# Merging based on nearest values in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying my best to explain the issue im facing while doing merging.

I have two dataframes with timestamp unix numbers in common.

lets keep it as df1 and df2

```
df1
price1 timestamp
10     16454526519
23     16454527130
30     16454527200

df2
price2 timestamp
11     16454526518
24     16454527130
34     16454527205
```

if i merge based on df1, there is Nan values for the timestamps which are not present. I will forward fill those. I dont want that to be done because df2 may have timestamp a bit longer.

Merging behavior

```
timestamp     price1  price2
16454526519.   10.     nan
16454527130.   23.     24
16454527200.   30.     nan
```

Expecting behaviour

Want to merge in default manner and use forward or backward fill to remove nans and then demerge df1.

```
     timestamp     price1  price2
    16454526519.   10.     11
    16454527130.   23.     24
    16454527200.   30.     34
```

Note: i need to forward or backward fill only when it is lower than 5 seconds differance at max.

Comment: Kindly share your merge code

Comment: Check out pd.merge_asof